# Open and display data from file

Tags: java

I have a file that contains score data for a game (the player name and their final score.

I want to open the file and have the data contained to be displayed so that it would look something like

`PLAYER           SCORE
 ------           -----
 John             1000
 Steve            2000`

The file is definitely saving the data that I want but I cannot get it to display the data.

I have tried various things along the lines of:

```
public static void loadScores() {
    boolean fileIsValid;
    String filename = "";
    File file;
    do {
        fileIsValid = true;
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLEADERBOARDS");
        printWave();
        if (!fileIsValid) {
            System.out.print("\n\nSorry, commander, your file name: " + filename + " does not exist.");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        filename = "scores.gz";
        file = new File(filename);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            fileIsValid = false;
        }
    } while (!fileIsValid); 
    System.out.println(file);
    pressKey();
}
```

Comment: And how should that method display anything? You're just checking if that file exists and nothing else. ... oh `System.out.println(file);` this is not the way to read and print the content of a file. Google for a tutorial, there are plenty of them available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
public static void loadScores() {
    File file = null;
    try{
        file = new File("scores.gz");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
            }
            fileReader.close();
        } else {
            System.out.print("\n\nSorry, commander, your file name: " + filename + " does not exist.");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Your original code will sit in an infinite loop until the file is created!  Also there is no sleep in your loop, thus you will query the file system continuously without a wait period.

This doesn't require 3rd party libraries but Apache commons has some nice util classes, also for reading files: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/description.html